# How to integrate GCM in android.mk project

Tags: android, android.mk

I would like to integrate GCM(Google Cloud Message) in android.mk projects. I know we have a latest version of FCM. Still I have to use GCM due to server side implementation. I am able to achieve GCM using build.gradle(Android Studio) same thing to I have to port in android.mk project.

I have added all google-play-services(.aar files) in libs folder and we are able to build the project. Using GCM token we are trying to send the notifications. We unable to receive the notifications. Same code is working fine in build.gradle(android studio).

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Just an FYI GCM servers are going to be shut down April 11, 2019

Comment: What can GCM do that FCM can not do? @Prasanna

Comment: I am ok with even FCM also but point here is how can we integrate FCM/GCM like android.mk projects. If it is build.gradle projects we can easily do this.